# Persist a Spring Java Object into Magnolia repository

Tags: spring, jcr, persist, magnolia

If i had an additional Spring application extending my Magnolia, which gets some Java Object, which will be used inside my application, how can i save it ???
I already learned to do queries, but i cannot use it yet to put something in or change it. I can only fetch data. into nodes.
where or how do i persist ??

For Info: I have a repository which shall store the special data and i have a nodetype declared for this. As it is now the spring social UserConnection i have the workspace "connections" with nodeType mgnl:userConnection

My JavaObject is a UserConnection, designed near to MgnlUser, so i also add properties, but i don't know yet, what to do with path and uuid.
i don't know yet how to declare it or where to get it.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the data same way as you fetch it. Assuming you are running your spring app through Magnolia filter chain you have MgnlContext setup for given thread and can easily call `MgnlContext.getJCRSession("connections")` to obtain the session and node same way you do to retrieve your data, to add subnodes or set properties on given node you just call `node.addNode("myNewNode")` or `node.setProperty("myProp", "newValue")` on the node and follow that with call to `session.save()` to persist the session info. But I guess you already know all that.

If you want to get whole object serialised into repo for you by system instead, you can use JackRabbit OCM for this, or even easier - use integration of OCM into Magnolia - http://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MJROCM
. It's already used in Shop module of Magnolia if you are looking for examples on how to work with OCM.

HTH,
Jan